# How to read a csv file script Python?

Tags: python, django, csv

How to read a csv file script Python?

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
     print row
```

gives this error

```
python2 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
import csv
File "/home/miruss/virtualbox/csv.py", line 4, in <module>
  f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the reason for the error do not understand.

Comment: Emm... error doesn't match your script

Comment: You might want to edit your post with the code fragments that are necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from "sys.argv[1]".

You meant to execute your code against the file name.

python2 test.py filename.csv

Comment: good job for actually seeing that his question really had nothing to do with csv ...

Comment: python2 test.py some.csv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/home/miruss/virtualbox/csv.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = csv.reader(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'

Answer (score 0):

```
print list(csv.reader(open("somefile.csv")))
```

would work I think